# Attempt to Save As greys out window

Tags: firefox, gedit

I'm new to Ubuntu, so any help will be appreciated.

When editing a file in Gedit, I can't save it to a different file name. Keying Ctrl-Shift-S causes the window to be greyed out. Same thing if I click the three-bar menu to the right of the word Save. Clicking the Save button seems to save the file with the same name.

Also the same thing happens if I try to save from a website page in Firefox. Right-click on anything (link, image, etc.) and choose Save As causes the Firefox window to be greyed out.

Thanks!

Comment: We don't know what files you've been trying to edit, and where to save them.  Why it matters? System files editing require admin privileges granted by `sudo`. Saving files anywhere outside your home folder also requires privilege escalation - `sudo`. So, two questions: what and where?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'm editing a file I created in gedit.It lives in /home/Albertinnc/Documents.  I can change the file and save it, but if I try Save As (Ctrl-Shift-S), the gedit window is overlaid with grey and the only thing I can do is press Esc. Is there a default Save As destination I might not have permission to? Still it is weird it doesn't give me the option to change it.

Comment: More information:  The same thing happens when I go into Files and do a right-click Copy To. The Window is greyed out and I dot get a chance to tell it where to copy the file to.

Comment: This is a strange behavior. It looks as if gedit and firefox try to save outside your home folder. Not sure why that is.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same issue!

Edit: This solved my problem. The OS thought I had two displays. Settings > Devices > System Display > Change to single display.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2376761